# Angular. Property 'subscribe' does not exist on type 'void'.ts(2339)

Tags: angular

I've just added a new module (experiencia) in my project and this error is happening. On the other module(estudios) I have almost the same code and no error occurs.

The error that I get is:[image]

experiencia.component.ts

```
  onSubmit() {
    let experiencia: Experiencia = this.experienciaForm.value;
    if (this.experienciaForm.get('id')?.value == '') {
      this.porfolioService.guardarNuevaExperiencia(experiencia).subscribe(
        (nuevaExperiencia: Experiencia) => {
          this.experienciaList.push(nuevaExperiencia);
        }
      );
    } else {
      this.porfolioService.modificarExperiencia(experiencia).subscribe(
        () => {
          this.reloadData();
        }
      )
    }
  }
```

Comment: Looks like your `modificarExperiencia` method didn't return any value. Please share the method. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

el "porfolioService.guardarNuevaExperiencia" debe tener un return en ese observable (en el servicio), de otra manera no puedes subscribirte. revisa eso.